# Embed many graphics using an array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, embedding, assets

In AS3 you can embed a graphic into a Class variable:

```
     [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="topSquare")]
        public var TopMenuItem:Class;
```

I have hundreds of assets in this one website project I'm doing, so I want to embed assets into an array for quick access.

Can I do something like this? Its not compiling so I'm wondering whether its possible.

```
        public var MenuAssets:Array = [
           [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="topSquare")],
           [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="botSquare")],
           [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="leftSquare")],
           [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="rightSquare")],
        ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also embed the assets in a single FLA. In the FLA's library, give each one a class name like "graphics.menu.RightSquare" then export it as a SWC. Configure your Flash Builder project to load the SWC as an external library. Then you can do something like:

```
import graphics.menu.*;

new RightSquare();
```

Comment: Fantastic solution! Thanks a million, you've really saved me from a lot of manual [Embed] work.

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid you can't. What you could do is the following:

```
public class Assets {
    [Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="topSquare")]
    public static const TOP_SQUARE:Class;
    //... more assets ...
    public static function getAssets():Array {
        var ret:Array = [];
        for each (var s:String in describeType(Assets).constant.@name) ret.push(Assets[s]);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 That's cool! Maybe you can prefix all asset names with a unique string and filter them out from the constant.@name - just in case there are other constants declared in the same class.

Comment: @Amarghosh: good idea. OTOH, I think it would make sense to separate assets and actual constants into seperate classes.

Comment: I did this but ArgumentError: Error #2100: The ByteArray parameter in Loader.loadBytes() must have length greater than 0.
 at flash.display::Loader/_loadBytes()
 at flash.display::Loader/loadBytes()

Comment: @coderex I got this error when I load assets in iOS and was using TLF text. I needed to add the assets library to the swf that I loaded. I don't know if it was your case.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the metadata tags in Flex apply to a class level variable.

> You must use the `[Embed]` [metadata tag](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/embed_3.html) before a variable definition, where the variable is of type Class.

You can however do:

```
[Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="topSquare")]
public var TopMenuItem:Class;

[Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="leftSquare")]
public var LeftMenuItem:Class;

[Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="rightSquare")]
public var RightMenuItem:Class;

[Embed(source="MenuAssets.swf", symbol="botSquare")]
public var BottomMenuItem:Class;

public var menuAssets:Array = [TopMenuItem, LeftMenuItem, 
                               RightMenuItem, BottomMenuItem];
```

Comment: +1. But you can generate the array automatically, as shown in my answer. ;)